# How can you aggregate queried nodes grouped by user ID?

Tags: 8, nodes

In Drupal 8, trying to figure out how to query all nodes in grouped by `uid` with a conditional using the following code:

```php
$nids = Drupal::entityQueryAggregate('node')
  ->condition('field_boolean', 'true')
  ->groupBy('uid')
  ->aggregate('nid', 'COUNT')
  ->execute();
```

This is the following result I get from debugging:

[image: Results of execution]

I'm instead looking for an array of node ID's that belong to a single `uid`, so say if the user created 4 nodes in this example then I would like the node ID's instead of the `COUNT` result given by the above query.

Comment: could't  you just do this with a normal entity query and a foreach loop ?

Comment: Yes, however I'm just curious if there wasn't any way to do this in one go with an aggregate query, especially if something more powerful could be used that might involve more loops if that's possible.

Comment: Aggregation is for counting things and summarizing row data. I don't think that `::entityQueryAggregate()` is the right tool for your job. I would use `::entityQuery` instead. You should then be able to narrow down by user with a `condition()` clause: `->condition('uid', $target_uid)`. You probably don't need to group your results, either.